# What is a good way to keep a small amount of state between Heroku deployments?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, state

I have a small Node.js app running on Heroku that currently does not need or have any persistent storage of state.

However, I want to add a feature that requires that a few very small pieces of state (less than 1KB of data) be persisted between deployments.

What is the best way for me to add this state to my Heroku app, while still retaining the ability for this app to be easily deployed with the "Deploy to Heroku" button?

So far the only potential solution I see would involve attaching a free PostgreSQL addon, which seems like massive overkill.

Comment: `free PostgreSQL addon, which seems like massive overkill.` - I take it you are not talking from experience, for it takes just a few lines of code to persist data into PostgreSQL, and is quite trivial.

Comment: I'm happy to accept a PostgreSQL-based solution, but I was just unsure if that was indeed a good route forward for this specific use case. I also wouldn't know what would be a good way to also utilize PostgreSQL in a one-click deployment. For instance, how would I handle creating the initial tables in a one-click deployment? These are questions that I've not been able to find answers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addons like Postgres and Redis can still be used with the Heroku Deploy button. Check out this example for how initial table building (via rake and stuff) work: https://blog.heroku.com/introducing_the_app_json_application_manifest

Comment: Yeah, a small Redis store looks like the way to go. I spoke with Heroku support and they confirmed this. Thanks!

Comment: @Lange If you decide to go the way of PostgreSQL, then [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is the easiest one to use, especially for such a small task that you need ;)